# Update multiple Ids when SET = (Sql Query)

Tags: sql-server, performance, primary-key, query-performance

I want to update multiple records however the value being set is based on the primary key of the given record. This is not an issue with a single record as I can use:

```
UPDATE T1
     SET A1 = (SELECT TOP 1 X FROM T2 WHERE Y = ID1)
     WHERE A2 = ID1
```

The IN operator works fine for the WHERE clause as it will update the correct list but not in the sub query. In the SET it will get the top 1 from all values in the ID list and I just want it for that corresponding record/ID.

Using: Microsoft T-SQL

Thank You

Answer (score 5):

Instead of specifying the same IN list for both `Y` and `A2`, specify it only for `A2` and make the subquery correlate with `T1` on `T2.Y = T1.A2`, like this:

```
UPDATE
  dbo.T1
SET
  A1 = (SELECT TOP 1 T2.X FROM dbo.T2 WHERE T2.Y = T1.A2)
WHERE
  A2 IN (ID1, ID2, ...)
;
```

This way the subquery will pick the topmost row from `T2` that matches the key of the `T1` row being updated.

Please note also that using `TOP n` without `ORDER BY` will result in an arbitrary row being selected. If there can be two or more distinct values of `X` per `Y` in `T2`, it might be a good idea to make the results deterministic by introducing an `ORDER BY` clause with specific enough set of sorting criteria.

On the other hand, if `X` stays the same per `Y`, you are probably storing redundant information in `T2`. Perhaps, in that case you should move the `X` column to `T1`, based on the facts that *a)* `T2.Y` appears to be a reference to `T1.A2` and *b)* `A2` is the primary key of `T1`.